# Using Amazon Certificates with Postfix and Dovecot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail, amazon-certificate-manager

If I generate a certificate through Amazon Certificate Manager, can I somehow use it within my EC2 instance? I want to migrate my existing email service (both SMTP and IMAP servers) using Postfix and Dovecot to AWS, and in the configuration I would like to use Amazon certificates, if this is at all possible. I looked into Amazon SES, but they do not offer an IMAP server. An alternative option is Amazon WorkMail, but I don't think it supports migration for my particular setup, and I'd like to retain as much control and customization as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Amazon certificates are only available for Amazon resources, you cannot use them on self managed resources (i.e. EC2) it's not a certificate that you can download and use.